OAuth 2 - The refresh token generated before a scope expansion will remain valid after it (with the original scopes)?
Consider the following scenario:

I have an Oauth 2 app configured to ask permission for scopes A and B;
Clients give me permission, and I store their refresh tokens securely.

If I change the scope this app asks to ask A, B, and C, will the refresh tokens that I have stored before the change remain valid?
I expect originally generated refresh tokens to remain valid.

the original refresh token will be valid but only with the original scopes

@LindaLawton-DaImTo If you want, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.
